# CastingDevicePicker custom styles

Tags: c#, uwp

How to change the main colors of CastingDevicePicker, I need to change the background, but I can't do it. CastinDevicePicker class has the `Appearance` property, but when I set it nothing happens.

Comment: Could you please share the code about how do you do that?